# gl_FragCoord precision

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I have this fragment shader code that displays differently between iOS simulator (non-retina) and iPad2 (non-retina) :

```
     highp vec2 textCoord;
     textCoord.x = gl_FragCoord.x / uViewPortWidth;
     textCoord.y = gl_FragCoord.y / uViewPortHeight;

     highp vec4 resultColor = texture2D(uTexture, textCoord);

     gl_FragColor = resultColor;
```

Somehow in real device, the result is jagged. But in simulator, it's smooth as hell.

Real device :

[image: iOS device jagged]

Is it because of precision problem of the gl_FragCoord? Weird how it only works on simulator...

Any tips how to deal with gl_FragCoord? Thanks!

Comment: Which simulator are you using, and which iPad are you using? Because it might matter if the device has a retina display or not, and if the simulator you're using is retina or not.

Comment: Oh yeah, I edited the question. It's both Non-Retina iPad. Don't have real retina iPad , so can't test them..

Answer (score 2):

`gl_FragCoord` is defined as `mediump`. So compliant implementations of ES 2 can give it as little as 10 bits of storage. However ES doesn't place an upper limit, so another equally compliant implementation may discard the precision modifiers and treat everything as a 16-bit (or greater) type.

It also stipulates that:

> The precision used to internally evaluate an operation, and the
>   precision qualification subsequently associated with any resulting
>   intermediate values, must be at least as high as the highest precision
>   qualification of the operands consumed by the operation.

So the precision used to perform your calculations will be at least `mediump` — or `highp` if that's how `uViewPortWidth/Height` are declared.

However exactly what precision that gives you is still implementation dependant. Anecdotally, the simulator does generally use a higher precision.

So, as a first attempt, make sure that divide is `highp` by any means. If that doesn't get the precision you want then the GPU likely doesn't provide it in a single unit so you'll have to consider a more complicated solution.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your explanation. I made lowp for all variables, and the result is still smooth on simulator. Weird. I'm going to test using a more complicated solution (using triangle strip instead of points...)

Comment: @Coolant: You should not use points in the first place if you care about precision. They have several unusual properties: **(1)** they are not always square, if anti-aliasing is enabled they are round; **(2)** they have an implementation-defined minimum and maximum size range and will be clamped to that range ([1,1] is the default range), **(3)** they have a different origin depending on whether the size is even or odd and **(4)** they can have variable granularity when clamping to the supported size range. They are terrible primitives and I make a point to use them as little as possible.